# FormData is an object with an Array of Arrays

Tags: react-native, expo, form-data

In JS, the FormData object compiles to a set of key/value pairs to be sent  using XMLHttpRequest. But I am unable to achieve that in my React Native Expo Application, as when I declare a new FormData object in react Native expo application, I get an object of Array of Arrays instead which looks like below.

**My Declaration:**

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', info.title)
    formData.append('standard', info.standard)
    formData.append('details', info.details)
```

**The formData object in console log looks like this:**

```
  _parts[
      Array [
        "title",
        "Yooha",
    ],
    Array [
         "standard",
         "700",
    ],
    Array [
         "details",
         "Yaot",
   ],

]
```

**How I expect my object to look like:**

```
object :{
    title:'yooha',
    standard:'700,
    details:'yoot'
}
```

Any help on this will be grateful. I have done lots of research on this and I do not see where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: have you found any solution for this. Please share

Comment: Had same issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of formData use react-native-fetch-blob.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this blog post about how to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask